# Using a4j:support with jsf 1.2

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2, selectonemenu

I need to make some save action on h:selectonemenu. When it's value change then it should save this value, but without page refresh (so without submit).

Unfortunatelly I must work with jsf 1.2. After some research I've found that it can be done with a4j:support, however I have no idea how to include it into my project. Do I need to download some old richfaces libraries ? (as i know richfaces 4 doesnt support jsp syntax). Or does exists some other way to achieve this goal ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. You could use Richfaces 3.3.4.Final (downaload [here](http://downloads.jboss.org/richfaces/releases/3.3.X/3.3.4.Final/richfaces-ui-3.3.4.Final-bin.zip)).**

[This](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/GettingStarted.html) is way you should include, register and use libraries in a project. Notice:

> A JSF application with RichFaces assumes that the following JARs are available in the project: commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar, commons-collections-3.2.jar, commons-digester-1.8.jar, commons-logging-1.0.4.jar, jhighlight-1.0.jar.

Example (from [developer guide](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_support.html)) for your case:

```
<h:form id="planetsForm">
<h:outputLabel value="Select the planet:" for="planets" />
<h:selectOneMenu id="planets" value="#{planetsMoons.currentPlanet}" valueChangeListener="#{planetsMoons.planetChanged}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{planetsMoons.planetsList}" />
    <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="moons" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:dataTable id="moons" value="#{planetsMoons.moonsList}" var="item">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{item}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

**2. Example of other solution:**

You could use jQuery.ajax() with custom servlet.

JS:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/app/customservlet.jsf?value=' + selectOneValue; //selected value
});
```

Servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {     
    String selectOneValue = req.getParameter("value");      
    //do something
}
```

Comment: sorry for late response. I have a question regarding first solution. I was trying to add richfaces library to my project but without success. It throws an error during a startup `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.richfaces.webapp.taglib.UIComponentELTagBase from`. But this class exists in my war in richfaces library. What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: oh, and i'm running it on JBoss

Comment: Did you put libs directly or by maven declaration? (all of them: richfaces-api-3.3.4.Final + richfaces-impl-3.3.4.Final + richfaces-ui-3.3.4.Final)

Comment: this project is build with ant. i use ivy to configure it. And after build output WAR has all of these libs in WEBINF/lib directory inside WAR.

Comment: ok, my fault. I specified wrong version of jsf which I use. I'm using jsf 1.1. I replace 3.3.4 version with 3.1.6.SR1 and it works fine. Thank you